# Obtaining a handle for newly created map in GeoExt

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

Hopefully a straightforward question...

I am following the example based on this page here http://www.geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/MapPanel.html to create a map within a window, here's my code:

```
new Ext.Window({
    title: "GeoExt MapPanel Window",
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    layout: "fit",
    items: [{
        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
        id: "mappanel",
        layers: [basemap],
        extent: "-5,35,15,55"
    }]
}).show();
```

So the above example create a new map in a floating window which is exactly what I'm after...  My question is how exactly do I get a handle to the map within this new window so I can add controls and layers after the map has been created?  Something along the lines of:

```
map = grab_the_map_somehow_from_Ext.Window_above();
map.addControl(my_new_control);
map.addLayers([my_new_layer]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: mapPanel = Ext.getCmp("mappanel"); > http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/mappanel-window.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the map as an OL Map separately, then assign it to the mappanel.  Works for me.

var map;
map = new OpenLayers.Map();

...

items: [{
        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
        **map : map,** //  <--- add this
        id: "mappanel",
        layers: [basemap],
        extent: "-5,35,15,55"
    }]
...

map.AddControl(yourControlHere);

@Mapperez solution will manipulate the Ext panel, and OL will not (I think) recognize it as a valid map object.